# Protect baby from mains

Tags: mains

My little baby is now mobile and I'm afraid he gets his hand in the mains slot. I planned to buy this dummy cover from amazon but the reviews said it's safer not to use it at all.

People say it cancels the ground or something.

The slots in my house are UK ones with the on/off button. All of them are quite low and reachable.

Comment: Protect mains from babies or babies from mains?

Comment: sorry protect the baby

Comment: You might want to edit to complete your last sentence.

Comment: @ThePhoton hopefully thedude wasn't poking a dinner fork into the mains socket while typing.

Comment: Spehrp amd Phorton, post is edited, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't mess with the sockets**

Modern (i.e. post 1950) sockets in the UK are very good. They are designed to make it very difficult to get a shock. There are three pins, earth, live and neutral. Earth is the one at the top, and is safe to touch, live and neutral are below, and have plastic shutters protecting them.  When you put a plug in, the earth pin goes first, and pushes on a lever to open the shutters. So the only way to get a shock is to push a pin in the top hole, then stick your fingers in the bottom one.  The socket protectors are bad, because when you push them into the socket, they open the shutters. So there is no improvement, and in fact it makes the socket slightly less safe, because sometimes the cheap plastic earth pin breaks off, and leaves the shutters open.

[This doesn't apply to foreign sockets, which usually don't have shutters, so protectors can be useful.]

**Things you could do instead**

- Chuck out any cheap adaptors or extension cords which don't have the shutters. They aren't legal in the UK anyway.
- Chuck out any plugs which don't have plastic covers on the live and neutral pins. Those pins should have a thin plastic sleeve, usually black, over part of their length. Only the earth pin should be bare metal for it's full length. Again, plugs with unprotected pins are not legal.
- Check cheap plugs with interchangeable/international pins. Make sure that if the plug is taken apart, the back of the live/neutral pins don't stick out.
- Always buy electronics from reputable sellers, and make sure every mains powered item has a CE mark.
- Check your electrical goods. Repair or replace anything with worn out or damaged power cables/plugs.
- Avoid trailing cables, and make absolutely sure there are no hanging loops of cable your baby could get tangled in.

For more advice, including non-electrical safety, talk to your local Citizen's Advice and/or NHS services. It's free, and they are very helpful.

Comment: Bear in mind on your point (4) that the CE mark is put on by the manufacturer. It doesn't mean the item has passed any test by an independent tester or even themselves. There is a lot of rubbish coming from certain countries at the moment with CE marks on it that mean absolutely nothing regarding the quality and safety of the item.

Comment: A manufacturer or importer who introduces a product to the market with a CE mark but no tests is breaking the law. It is depressingly common though.  The "reputable sellers" bit is more important - don't buy electronics from ebay.

Comment: I don't think that people posting stuff from China care much about EU law, frankly.

Comment: I live in France, and all sockets sold since a long time have shutters too (and it's sometimes pretty annoying with cheap sockets, the damn thing doesn't want to open even when properly inserting a plug). I think it is mandatory. I also think it is the case in most european countries, not only UK.

Answer (score 4):

UK sockets are shuttered. The shutter can only be opened with a plug, or a suitable tool. That push-on dummy cover is a suitable tool. When used upside down, it will open the shutters on the live and neutral pins without covering them! By using plastic covers, you are supplying your infant with a suitable tool to open the shutters, exactly where he needs it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything. The UK socket is very safe, it has an internal shutter so there is no path for anything to poke into the live (or neutral).

There is a campaign to stop people using the plug-in covers you've seen, since they make the socket if anything more dangerous, since pushed in incorrectly they can push the shutter out of the way by just pushing into the Earth pin.

Neither can a person (even a tiny one) get a shock from a partially pulled out plug since the pins are shrouded.

Really, there is simply no need to do anything with your sockets. They are safe as houses.

Comment: The campaign is by The IET http://www.fatallyflawed.org.uk/ and supported by the NHS

Comment: You may occasionally find plugs with all-metal (unshrouded) pins - but you're unlikely to, they will be over 40 years old. If you do, have them replaced with newer plugs.

Answer (score 1):

The UK socket is quite resiliant unless someone determined pokes a small conducting bar through the protective shroud on the live terminal.

The worser scenario is cheap chinese (nothing against szechuan beef) made wall-warts used for charging androids and such like plugged-in and left plugged-in. Your little guy might sneak behind the sofa and kick off what is meant to be the ill-fitting and badly glued plastic protection cover over said wall-wart and expose his little fingers to 320 V DC.

This is far more likely through experience.

Comment: My sister-in-law kicked a wall wart USB charger off the wall.  It left the prongs (blades) in the outlet; very dangerous! We had to turn off the breaker before pulling them out with pliers.

Comment: My grandson did the same but got shocked behind the sofa - I knew he got shocked because he didn't want to talk about it. Hey he's OK!

Comment: I'm in the USA, and every adult I know has been shocked by mains at least once. The outlets aren't safe, but at least the voltage is lower :)  Glad your grandson is OK!

Answer (score 0):

Erm, people say a lot of nonsense. The covers will not "cancel the ground" - that statement doesn't even make sense.

You will have no problem using the covers to stop little fingers getting in there.

---

As a side note, in the UK, the modern socket design is far superior to those in say the US. Modern sockets have built in covers which prevent the insertion of anything (including fingers and bits of metal) into the live/neutral contacts without a ground pin being first inserted (the ground pin opens the built in covers).

The design makes it quite difficult to get an electric shock as you first have to insert something into the ground hole, and then insert something else into the live/neutral hole.

However this only applies if you don't have old sockets (if you take a look at the socket you should see a plastic cover just inside the live/neutral holes).

Comment: "Cancel the ground" is probably a misinformed way of saying that it has a part that goes in to the ground socket, opening the covers for the live and neutral sockets. I.e., it cancels the protection provided by this feature in the new sockets.